# excel inputbox vba cancel function

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have a macro which is working well. But the issue I have is with the *InputBox*. The macro is running into errors when the user presses **CANCEL** or **X** out of the *InputBox*. What can I do to stop this from happening. If the user presses **X** or **Cancel** the process should end, ie. exit the sub.  My code is below:

```
Sub FindValues()    
    Dim LSearchRow As Integer
    Dim rw As Integer, cl As Range, LSearchValue As Long, LCopyToRow As Integer
    Dim iHowMany As Integer
    Dim aSearch(15) As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    ' clear the sheets before it runs so to accurate number of funds opend.

    Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("tier 2").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("tier 3").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("tier 4").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("tier 5").Cells.ClearContents

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute
    FixC
    Sheet2.Cells.Clear
    Sheet1.Select
    iHowMany = 0
    LSearchValue = 99

    'this for the end user to input the required A/C to be searched

    Do While LSearchValue <> 0
        LSearchValue = InputBox("Please enter a value to search for. Enter a zero to indicate finished" & _
    "entry.", "Enter Search value")
        If LSearchValue <> 0 Then
            iHowMany = iHowMany + 1
            If iHowMany > 15 Then
                MsgBox "You are limited to 15 search numbers.", vbOKOnly, "Limit reached"
                iHowMany = 15
                Exit Do
            End If
            aSearch(iHowMany) = LSearchValue
        End If
    Loop

    If iHowMany = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No selections entered.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "No Search data"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    LCopyToRow = 2

    For rw = 1 To 1555
        For Each cl In Range("D" & rw & ":M" & rw)
        '------------------------------------------------
            For i = 1 To iHowMany
                Debug.Print cl.Row & vbTab & cl.Column
                LSearchValue = aSearch(i)
                If cl = LSearchValue Then
                    cl.EntireRow.Copy
                    'Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2")
                    '.Rows(LCopyToRow & ":" & LCopyToRow)
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                    Rows(LCopyToRow & ":" & LCopyToRow).Select
                    'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
                       xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    'Move counter to next row
                    LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
                    'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
                End If
            Next i
            'LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
        Next cl
    Next rw
    'Position on cell A3
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheet2.Select
    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if `LSearchValue` is empty. Use this do loop

```
Do While LSearchValue <> 0
    LSearchValue = InputBox("Please enter a value to search for. Enter a zero to indicate finished" & _
    "entry.", "Enter Search value")

    If LSearchValue = "" Then
        Exit Do '<~~ Or Exit Sub if you want to terminate the sub
    ElseIf LSearchValue <> 0 Then
        iHowMany = iHowMany + 1
        If iHowMany > 15 Then
            MsgBox "You are limited to 15 search numbers.", vbOKOnly, "Limit reached"
            iHowMany = 15
            Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: If OP wants to terminate the routine on *Cancel* `Exit Sub` will suit well as pointed out in the question.

Comment: Siddharth i am getting an error of "13 type mismatch" with that. I just trying to make the code more robust. It wont be professional to have an error occur for the user. I have also tried error handlers , no success.

Comment: @kay: Change `Dim LSearchRow As Integer` to `Dim LSearchRow As Variant`

Comment: Na no success , still searching for the answer . I have tried different variations of it. Maybe the input my not be most appropriate for this situation.

Comment: @Kay: It works for me. Are you sure you are using it as I have mentioned above?

Comment: can you post the full code you using? please.when you cancel the input-box or X out you not getting errors ?